# Reference request for a theorem on maps to normal varieties with equidimensional fibers being open

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

I am requesting a reference for a proof.. I believe that it is due to Chevalley. A theorem by Chevalley says that if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a dominant morphism of irreducible varieties, then there is an open set $U \subset Y$ such that $f|_{f^{-1}(U)}:f^{-1}(U)\rightarrow U$ is an open map. The proof I wish to seek proves the following: if furthermore, $Y$ is normal and $f$ has equidimensional fibers.. then $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an open map.
I have a footnote that says this result may be found in "Fondement de la geometrie algebrique" by Chevalley, but I cannot read French..

Thank you!

Comment: This is Theorem 14.129 in Görtz/Wedhorn, but they don't prove it, and refer the reader to EGAIV${}_3$, 14.4.4. [David Rydh's thesis](https://people.kth.se/~dary/thesis/thesis-paperIV.pdf) is an English source with a proof—see Cor. 6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely Corollary 17.4.11 in the Book *Lie Algebras and Algebraic Groups* by Patrice Tauvel and Rupert Yu. I find the book quite well-readable.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for.. Thank you!